# overlap text in top of a div

Tags: css, text, bootstrap-4, overlap

I'm trying to overlap a text in a div like this. I'm using Bootstrap but can be using CSS. The example in the image but I really need the text go a little bit under.

[image of the example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPWvo.png)

I've tried

```
<h3 class="text-center" style="margin: 0px 0px -10px 0px">WebDevelopment.</h3>


<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="box2" >
        <h4>alo</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="box3" >
            <h4>alo</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

[the resut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3dta.png)

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Stackoverflow isn't a place for us to do your coding for you. Show what you have written so far and what problems you are running into. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "z-index" in your h3 tag. i wrote some code for you kindly check this.

```
h3{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.box2{
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
  float:left;
}

.box3{
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
  float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `position: relative`:

```
<h3 class="text-center" style="margin: 0px 0px -10px 0px;position: relative;">WebDevelopment.</h3>
```

More information about **position** at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp